# Its possible to use a RecycleView with kivy only in a part of the screen?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-recycleview

I'm to do a film screen where there is a poster, a synopsis and other information about the film, and under there i would like to show in what theaters are showing the movie, but the code when i try in a separate screen, alone, works fine, but when i put inside a GridLayout to show the cinemas it wont work.

````
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import api_test
from kivy.clock import Clock
import os
import json
from models import Cinemas

Builder.load_file('film_screen.kv')

class CinemaWidget(BoxLayout):
    name = StringProperty()
    close_to = StringProperty()
    price = BooleanProperty()

class FilmsScreen(Screen):
    movie_data = {}
    movie_title = StringProperty()
    movie_poster = StringProperty()
    movie_overview = StringProperty()
    movie_year = StringProperty()
    movie_credit = {}
    movie_director = StringProperty()
    movie_id =  {}
    movie_country = StringProperty()
    movie_genre = StringProperty()

    recycleView = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Cinemas = []

        # Lendo o arquivo JSON e transformando em uma lista de objetos Cinemas
        dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'cinemas.json')
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            cinemas_data = json.load(file)
            for cinema_data in cinemas_data:
                cinema = Cinemas(**cinema_data)
                self.Cinemas.append(cinema)

    def on_parent(self, widget, parent):
        self.recycleView.data = [{'name': cinema.name, 'close_to': cinema.close_to, 'price': cinema.price} for cinema in self.Cinemas]
  

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        
        movie_data = api_test.make_request()
        self.movie_title = movie_data['title']
        self.movie_overview = movie_data['overview']
        self.movie_year = movie_data['release_date']
        self.movie_genre = ', '.join(genre['name'] for genre in movie_data['genres'])

        for company in movie_data.get("production_countries", []):
            origin_country = company.get("name")
            if origin_country:
                self.movie_country = origin_country
                break

        # Necessary to access saved_images directory
        dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'poster_images/')
        saved_images = os.listdir(filename)
        # If already saved:
        if f'{api_test.selected_movie}.jpg' in saved_images:
            self.movie_poster = f'poster_images/{api_test.selected_movie}.jpg'
        else:
            self.movie_poster = ('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185' + movie_data['poster_path'])

        self.movie_director = next(
            (person['name'] for person in api_test.make_request_credits()["crew"] if
             person["known_for_department"] == "Directing"), None
        )

class ScrollViewCinemas(ScrollView):
    pass    ```

and the .kv file
````

: #:kivy!

```
#Background full editor
canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: 'design_files/R00_Fundo_filme.jpg' #Background lens image

    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: 'design_files/R00_Cinemas_Tela.png' #Background cinemas image

# Total editor
FloatLayout:

    # 01 "Go back" Button   
    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(70), dp(70)  
        background_normal: "design_files/Botão voltar.png"
        background_down: "design_files/Botão voltar verm.png"
        background_size: 'auto'
        background_allow_stretch: False
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'top': 1}

    # 02 Movie title
    Label:
        text: root.movie_title
        font_size: 30 
        font_name: 'design_files\The Beatrik.ttf'  
        halign: 'left'
        color: 64, 64, 64
        size_hint_x: 1  # Expand horizontally to fill the space
        size_hint_y: None  # Prevent automatic resizing vertically
        height: self.texture_size[1]  # Adjust height to fit content
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 0.9}

    # 03 Movie poster
    AsyncImage:
        source: root.movie_poster
        size_hint: 0.5, None
        height: self.width * (200 / 200)  #Proportion
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 0.8}
        keep_ratio: True
        allow_stretch: True

    # 04 Movie info
    ScrollView: #if it surpasses the height limit, scroll
        size_hint: 0.5, None
        height: dp(200)  # Set a fixed height or adjust as needed
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.5, 'top': 0.8, 'x': 0.45}

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(500)  # Set a fixed height or adjust as needed
            spacing: dp(5)
            color: 64,64,64

            #Year
            Label: 
                text: "[font=design_files/The Beatrik.ttf][size=15sp]Ano:[/size][/font] [font=design_files/Lucida Grande Bold.ttf][size=10sp]{}[/size][/font]".format(root.movie_year)
                markup: True
                halign: 'left'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None
            
            #Genre
            Label: 
                text: "[font=design_files/The Beatrik.ttf][size=15sp] Gênero:[/size][/font] [font=design_files/Lucida Grande Bold.ttf][size=10sp]{}[/size][/font]".format(root.movie_genre)
                markup: True
                halign: 'left'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None

            #Director
            Label:
                text: "[font=design_files/The Beatrik.ttf][size=15sp] Diretor:[/size][/font] [font=design_files/Lucida Grande Bold.ttf][size=10sp]{}[/size][/font]".format(root.movie_director)
                markup: True
                halign: 'left'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None

            Label: 
                text: "[font=design_files/The Beatrik.ttf][size=15sp] País:[/size][/font] [font=design_files/Lucida Grande Bold.ttf][size=10sp]{}[/size][/font]".format(root.movie_country)
                markup: True
                halign: 'left'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None

            Label:
                text: "[font=design_files/The Beatrik.ttf][size=15sp] Sinopse:[/size][/font] [font=design_files/Lucida Grande Bold.ttf][size=10sp]{}[/size][/font]".format(root.movie_overview)
                markup: True
                halign: 'left'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None


    #Cinemas -> Bottom part
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
        spacing: dp(5)
        color: 64, 64, 64

        recycleView: recycleView
        RecycleView:
            id: recycleView
            viewclass: 'CinemaWidget'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
```